# meta_query in WP_Query value is not accepting array

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I'm trying to pass an array of values into a meta_query value.

```
// Works as expected to return posts with 1474 in featured
'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'featured',  
                    'value' => 1474, 
                    'compare' => 'LIKE' 
                ) 
)   

// Works as expected to return posts with 2213 in featured
'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'featured',  
                    'value' => 2213, 
                    'compare' => 'LIKE' 
                ) 
)
```

However when I set as an array it does not work correctly. I am trying to return posts with 'featured' set to either 1474 or 2213.

```
// Does not work, wp_query returns all posts
'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'featured',  
                    'value' => array(1474, 2213), 
                    'compare' => 'LIKE' 
                ) 
)
```

I have also changed LIKE to IN with no success. I would like to stay away from multiple meta_query statements as the length of my array may change.

Comment: Does it work using the `IN` compare?

Comment: No, using IN returns no posts

Comment: What is the full meta value for `featured`?

Answer (score 0):

I manually added a "featured" meta key to 2 different posts with values of 1474 and 2213 and then ran a basic WP_Query() like so:

```
$qv = [
    'meta_query' =>[
        [
            'key'     => 'featured',  
            'value'   => [1474, 2213], 
            'compare' => 'IN',      
        ]
    ] 
];
$r = new WP_Query($qv);
```

It pulled up both posts.  This was query it generated:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
WHERE 1=1  
AND ( 
    ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'featured' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value IN ('1474','2213') )
) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 12
```

`var_dump()` out your `WP_Query()` and see what sql query WP is running.